# Split heterogeneous data from a single column into different column in Tableau

Tags: data-manipulation, tableau-desktop

I have a table with 13 columns and more than 1500 observations. I am interested in a particular column.it look like this:

```
| Lab   |
|:-----
|sample |
|sample |
|sample |
|sample |
|labs   |
|labs   |
|labs   |
```

I want to have something like this:

```
|lab   |    |sample|
|:-----|    |:-----|
|labs  |    |sample|
|labs  |    |sample|
|labs  |    |sample|
```

I went to my data source in Tableau and clicked on the `lab` column then `group` and `split` but I did not get the desired result.

any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an 'unpivot' operation, meaning you are going from rows -> columns.
There are two options:

1. Tableau Prep can accomplish this natively.  This comes with a Creator license.  It can modify your data and get it ready for analysis in Tableau.
2. You can create calculated members.
   Calculation 1: `if [Lab]='labs' then [Lab] end`
   Calculation 2: `if [Lab]='sample' then [Lab] end`

You can call each calculation by the column name that you want.